# Can I concatenate specific text with value of textfield in html before form post?

Tags: php, jquery, html, forms

I have two fields in survey form, Where I asks user about avg time between request and supply. I have two options one for weeks second for months. mean user can write either period in weeks or in months.

But I have to post text like `weeks` and `months` with specific user data. like `2 weeks` `5 weeks` `2 months` etc. How can I achieve this?

My Html code is here:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-2">
        <label>9. What is the average time between a Request and supplies?</label>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-xs-offset-3">
        <div class="input-group">
            <div class="input-group-btn">
                <a class="btn" disabled='disabled' style="font-weight:bold;color:black;">
                    <span>1.</span>
                </a>
            </div>
            <input name="avg_period" placeholder="" class="form-control" type="text">
            <div class="input-group-btn">
                <a class="btn" disabled='disabled' style="font-weight:bold;color:black;">
                    <span>Weeks</span>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>                         
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">
        <div class="input-group">
            <div class="input-group-btn">
                <a class="btn" disabled='disabled' style="font-weight:bold;color:black;">
                    <span>2.</span>
                </a>
            </div>
            <input name="avg_period" placeholder="" class="form-control" type="text">
            <div class="input-group-btn">
                <a class="btn" disabled='disabled' style="font-weight:bold;color:black;">
                    <span>Months</span>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>                         
    </div>
</div>
```

Other form tags and submit buttons etc definately exist in my form.

Comment: Capture the form submit event in JavaScript, modify the values before processing the event, then allow the event to continue processing.

Comment: but i have only one column in db where either weeks data will be saved or months, so i want to post only that text against which some value exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to all,

Your answeres are good but instead of those i choosed a soultion that I posts both fields to server and check there if both have value or anyone then I add week or month text with value on server and saves to db.

If you guys has other best options in your mind kindly post your answeres.

Thanks again for your efforts.

Answer (score 1):

Hope so this will help you a lot

```js
$(document).ready(function(e) {
  $("#btnSubmit").click(function(e) {
    $("#myuserName").val($("#myuserName").val() + "string to concaniate");

    //then submit the form mannually 

    // $("#myForm").submit();
   // return false;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="/actionName" method="Post" id="myForm">
  <input type="text" value="" name="userName" id="myuserName" />
  <input type="submit" value="submit" id="btnSubmit">
</form>
```

Comment: Remove `return false`.

Comment: why @Jai is that problem with this return false. actually on stackoverflow most of the time people are commenting to remove return false. what is the exact problem i never know.

Comment: Not required in this case. Will work without return false.

Comment: OK @Jai Thanks for your Suggestion. i have added it so as to my code should work before the form has submit and before request made. so as to my concatenate data should go on server. that's why  i have added return false and form submit before it. i.e i am submitting the form manually by jquery .submit() method. meanwhile just for assurity i have added return false.

Comment: `return false ` stops the default behavior of an element, that's why I mentioned to remove it and it will update the value before submitting.

Answer (score 1):

With pure JS, using IDs:

Output examples:

If both fields are empty: `0 weeks 0 months`
If weeks set to 1 and months is empty: `1 weeks 0 months`
If weeks set to 1 and months set to 1: `1 weeks 1 months`

```js
document.getElementById("avgTime").addEventListener("submit", function(e) {
  alert((document.getElementById("weeks").value || 0) + " weeks " + (document.getElementById("months").value || 0) + " months");
});
```

```html
<form id="avgTime">
  <label>9. What is the average time between a Request and supplies?</label><br>
  <span>1.</span>
  <input placeholder="" class="form-control" type="text" id="weeks">
  <span>Weeks</span><br>
  <span>2.</span>
  <input placeholder="" class="form-control" type="text" id="months">
  <span>Months</span><br>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Another solution (should be avoided): Using element position (This will works only if you have 2 inputs in your form. If you have more, you should change the position for `e.target[n]`).

```js
document.getElementById("avgTime").addEventListener("submit", function(e) {
  alert((e.target[0].value || 0) + " weeks " + (e.target[1].value || 0) + " months");
});
```

```html
<form id="avgTime">
  <label>9. What is the average time between a Request and supplies?</label><br>
  <span>1.</span>
  <input placeholder="" class="form-control" type="text">
  <span>Weeks</span><br>
  <span>2.</span>
  <input placeholder="" class="form-control" type="text">
  <span>Months</span><br>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it easily with js without loading jquery. Just enter week and month in the input and press conc it

```js
function conc() {
    var weeks = document.getElementById("weeks").value;
    var months = document.getElementById("months").value;
    var result = weeks.concat(months);
    
  alert(result);
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-2">
        <label>9. What is the average time between a Request and supplies?</label>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-xs-offset-3">
        <div class="input-group">
            <div class="input-group-btn">
                <a class="btn" disabled='disabled' style="font-weight:bold;color:black;">
                    <span>1.</span>
                </a>
            </div>
            <input id="weeks" placeholder="" class="form-control" type="Search">
            <div class="input-group-btn">
                <a class="btn" disabled='disabled' style="font-weight:bold;color:black;">
                    <span>Weeks</span>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>                         
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">
        <div class="input-group">
            <div class="input-group-btn">
                <a class="btn" disabled='disabled' style="font-weight:bold;color:black;">
                    <span>2.</span>
                </a>
            </div>
            <input id="months" name="searchParam" placeholder="" class="form-control" type="Search">
            <div class="input-group-btn">
                <a class="btn" disabled='disabled' style="font-weight:bold;color:black;">
                    <span>Months</span>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>                         
    </div>
</div>

<button onclick="conc()">Conc it</button>
```

Comment: This doesn't provide the "weeks" and "months" strings. The html inline property `onclick` should be avoided as it can be managed with JS.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I can suggest you is to use one input field and use javascript to get the values from there like:

```
<input type="text" id="getVal" name="name" value="enter value here">
<input type="button" name="name" value="Submit" onclick="getValue()">
<script type="text/javascript">
  function getValue(){
    var input = document.getElementById("getVal");
    var storeInputValue = input.value;
    if (storeInputValue) {
      var storeNumber = storeInputValue.match(/\d+/)[0]; // this will check and git first number from string
      var afterRemovingNumbers = storeInputValue.replace(/[0-9]/g, ''); // this returns a new string
      var afterRemovingWhiteSpaces = afterRemovingNumbers.replace(/\s/g, '');
      //now you can check if you have weeks or months
      if (afterRemovingWhiteSpaces == "week" || afterRemovingWhiteSpaces == "weeks") {
        alert(storeNumber + ' Week');
      }else if (afterRemovingWhiteSpaces == "month" || afterRemovingWhiteSpaces == "months") {
        alert(storeNumber + ' month');
      }
  }
</script>
```

Same function can be applied to both fields and many steps can be skip but to explain I have written every bit needed for the process

Comment: The html inline property onclick should be avoided as it can be managed with JS.

Comment: Of course that was just to explain. eventlistener can be added in JS.